# Why boundaries are common location for errors?

Tags: testing

We always frequently exercise Boundary-value analysis in test cases. Why boundaries are common locations for errors that result in software faults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a lot of comparisons are about checking if one item is bigger than another item. However, since these items are calculated in loops/iterations, sometimes the loop stops too soon or too late. This results in one or both of the items being 1 more or less than expected.

When comparing them with <, <=, > or >= it might be correct, except on the value one below, equal or one above the expected value, sometimes even 2 (when both items are one off, in the same direction).

For testers, depending on the risk, a test is made with the expected value, and if there is a higher risk, with a value plus and minus 1, and when there is even more risk, plus and minus 2. Of course this relates only to integers.

Example:

```
int i = f()
for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
{
   ...
}
```

if i returns 10, c will end with last value 9. However, maybe the programmer wanted to go until c is 10. Also 11 might be taken into account, if you want to test if the programmer did not make a mistake in < or <=.

Comment: Can you pls give me any example?

Comment: @user3698167 Example added

Answer (score 1):

Because people often think about the "ideal" use case when writing code, and don't naturally think of the weird cases.  An example would be `addNumbers(1, 2)`.  I expect that the return value would be the two values added.  I probably didn't think of adding negative numbers, or numbers that would max out `int` values, etc.  I wrote the code thinking of what it should do, not what it could be made to do.